# parent-child depth will change in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parent-child, depth

Please have a look at this project, in this project I have two symbol, one of them create and add another symbol as child.

Child symbol is drawn over parent as I expected. Parent symbol has two frames. When parent goes to second frame, child symbol drawn under parent. I mean depth order will change.
Can somebody help me!!?? Sorry for poor language.

Download link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-KCX3wxRH-cOUk5YU1OUzNFN3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: oh sorry i forgot mention this, please click on green button to change parent frame,

Answer (score 0):

Yellow shape from the frame 1 move to the new layer.

[image]

Hide Layer 3 and go to the second frame.

Select and remove the yellow bitmap image.

Show Layer 3.

---

Another solution:

Add next code after `gotoAndStop(2);`

```
swapChildren(btselect,getChildAt(numChildren - 1));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. but why its happens!!?? I think always child must drawn under parent, why change layer cause this? in this example I can merge layers, but if Yellow shape must has more than one layer, what should I do? is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand completely how the Flash rendering works so here's a couple of pointers:

"Child symbol is drawn over parent as I expected", nope, that doesn't happen. A parent has content which can be pictures, other symbols ect ... and they are all inside the parent so no child are drawn over the parent, they have a display hierarchy that's all.

"child symbol drawn under parent." well once again nope, a child is not drawn under it's parent, it is inside the parent and under other objects.

When a MovieClip with multiple frame displays the content of a frame it adds those content to it's display list (inside itself). After that if you add another child in it it will be on top. Then you move to another frame let's say frame 2. Once again the MovieClip adds the content of frame 2 inside itself, but since the child you added in the previous frame is already there all the new content is added on top of it.